# Is ubuntu-make still alive?

Tags: ubuntu-make

I just discovered ubuntu-make and it was really useful to install latest eclipse IDE (eclipse snap is outdated and is not really an option).

But... I'm not sure the ubuntu-make project is really alive and maintained...

Does anyone have insights on this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest commit was made 2 months ago, and the latest release was 21.10. So it seems it's still maintained.

https://github.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-make

Comment: You're right thanks. That said, not much talk about it. Never mind, it works !

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu make seems to be alive but I wonder if there is still ongoing support for it. There are no updates for Ubuntu 22.04. The Ubuntu Make wiki page is 5 years old and out of date. Currently there seem to be some bugs involved with setting up the icons in Ubuntu 22.04. The workaround is to choose the icon 'Add to Favorites' from the 'Show Applicatons Page' and NOT from the 'Launcher' bar on the left. I would be willing to assist with some of the documentation but really not sure how to get involved.